# NET MAUI How to create Picker selection changed behavior

Tags: maui, maui-community-toolkit

In the Net MAUI CommunityToolkit there is a behavior for Entry, SetFocusOnEntryCompletedBehavior,  that will focus on the provided visual element az a next input (the input that will be focused).
I did not find behavior for Picker or a DataPicker, and I tried to write my own based on theirs Entry behavior.

```
public class SetFocusOnPickerSelectedBehavior : BaseBehavior<VisualElement>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The <see cref="NextElementProperty"/> attached property.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly BindableProperty NextElementProperty = BindableProperty.CreateAttached(
            "NextElement",
            typeof(VisualElement),
            typeof(SetFocusOnPickerSelectedBehavior),
            default(VisualElement),
            propertyChanged: OnNextElementChanged);

    /// <summary>
    /// Required <see cref="GetNextElement"/> accessor for <see cref="NextElementProperty"/> attached property.
    /// </summary>
    public static VisualElement GetNextElement(BindableObject view) => (VisualElement)view.GetValue(NextElementProperty);

    /// <summary>
    /// Required <see cref="SetNextElement"/> accessor for <see cref="NextElementProperty"/> attached property.
    /// </summary>
    public static void SetNextElement(BindableObject view, VisualElement value) => view.SetValue(NextElementProperty, value);

    static void OnNextElementChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var picker = (Picker)bindable;
        var weakPicker = new WeakReference<Picker>(picker);
        picker.SelectedIndexChanged += SelectedIndexChanged;

        void SelectedIndexChanged(object? sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var picker = (Picker)sender;

            if (picker.SelectedIndex < 1)
                return;

            if (weakPicker.TryGetTarget(out var origPicker))
            {
                GetNextElement(origPicker)?.Focus();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The use:

```
<Picker x:Name="position" Title="Select..."
        temDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding Position, Mode=TwoWay}"
        toolkit:SetFocusOnPickerSelectedBehavior.NextElement="{x:Reference club}"/>
```

But I got an error:

**The attachable property 'NextElement' was not found in type 'SetFocusOnPickerSelectedBehavior'.**

thnx

Comment: a `BindableProperty` `xxxProperty` needs a corresponding property named `xxx`.  You need to define a `NextElement` property

Comment: https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui/blob/main/src/CommunityToolkit.Maui/Behaviors/AttachedBehaviors/SetFocusOnEntryCompletedBehavior.shared.cs
On the original code, I can't see where they defined it.

Comment: Interesting.  That's what the error message seems to clearly identify as the problem.  Maybe its defined in some base class?

Comment: Source has method pair Get/SetNextElement. Apparently that is now supported as an option. Maybe requires higher c# version?

Comment: I am already at net 7

Answer (score 0):

I found out that my mistake was, that I wanted to put my behavior in the same namespace like the the CommunityToolkit's:

```
namespace CommunityToolkit.Maui.Behaviors;
```

That not worked. I changed to my own namespace:

```
namespace Maui.Behaviors;
```

Imported in ContentPage xaml like:

```
xmlns:behaviors="clr-namespace:Maui.Behaviors"
```

Used on picker component like:

```
<Picker x:Name="position" Title="Select..."
        ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding Position, Mode=TwoWay}"
        behaviors:SetFocusOnPickerSelectedBehavior.NextElement="{x:Reference club}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else stumbles upon this, I had the same error but mine was due to selecting Content Page from the new item menu in visual studio instead of .NET MAUI Content Page.